# Как использовать cas инструкции при разработке модуля ядра linux?

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность, ядро, cas

Как использовать cas инструкции при разработке модуля ядра linux? Возникла потребность атомарно подменять указатель, как это реализовывается в ядре?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/546880/

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/staging/index.html#atomic-types